# Regex.Split considering letters and dashes

Tags: c#, regex

Such as for `Regex.Split(myString, @"\W+")`, what would be the right way to *avoid splitting* names that has dashes (`"-"`) like in the last name `"McMann-Stringer"`. I need to consider the name WITH the dash not splitting it.

Thank you!

Comment: why not `Regex.Split(myString, @"[^a-z_A-Z-0_9]+"` or `[^\w-]+` ?

Comment: Use a negated character class `[^\w-]+`

Comment: Could you please update to show expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try splitting on `[^\w-]`.  This says to split on not word characters, *except* for dash.  Your updated code:

```
Regex.Split(myString, @"[^\w-]+")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can *subtract* `-` from `\W` and split by `[\W-[\-]]+`:

```
string[] names = Regex.Split(myString, @"[\W-[\-]]+");
```